# animation on a Center Div using CSS transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I center a div in a slide using css transform like this

```
.img .inpo {
   border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    width: auto;

    z-index:5;
   margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

but the problem is that i would like to fade down this div on each slide so I use animate.css and apply it on the slide

```
.slick-active .inpo{

   animation:fadeInDown 1s both 1s;
}
```

and this broke the center div. I don't have any problem with fadeIn but with fadeInDown

the fadeInDown also use the css transform :

```
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      }

      to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    @keyframes fadeInDown {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      }

      to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    .fadeInDown {
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
      animation-name: fadeInDown;
    }
```

So I wonder if anyone knows how to use transform animation on a center div with transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the property `transform` on your centered `div`, it includes only the value `translate(x,y)`.

When you use your animation on it, there's a new set of values for `transform`: `translate3d` and later on `none`.

If you want to keep the original `transform` values, you're going to have to include it in your `transform` declared in the animation. Otherwise this will override any values in your original rules.

You're not using the Z value of `translate3d`, so I would just drop it and use `translate`. Use the following animation to fix it:

```
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

Remember to add the same for the `-webkit-` version.